# Error Installing KeyStone.Js on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, keystonejs

i'm trying to install keystone.js via windows cmd but its still got errors like this:

```
npm ERR! yo@1.3.3 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.3.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     yodoctor
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-keystone"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Pisa Family
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Users\Pisa Family>npm install -g yo
C:\Users\Pisa Family\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\Pisa Family\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\cli.js
```

i've tried to install yo package too, to try the yo doctor but it ends up failed too. here's the error log:

```
C:\Users\Pisa Family>npm install -g yo
C:\Users\Pisa Family\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\Pisa Family\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\cli.js

> yo@1.3.3 postinstall C:\Users\Pisa Family\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
> yodoctor


npm ERR! yo@1.3.3 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.3.3 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     yodoctor
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Pisa Family
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

i already search on google and still couldn't find any solutions (or maybe i missed one). need any advice and help, thx.

Comment: The latest version of Yeoman is 1.4.5. Not certain why you're installing 1.3.3. I would try to `npm uninstall -g yo` and `npm cache clean`. Then try to reinstall `npm install -g yo`.

Comment: Try open a new cmd as Administrator and then re-test the whole installation process.
Many times npm needs Admin attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try updating npm

```
npm install -g npm
```